# Infinite digest loop errors with Angular-Meteor, PublishComposite and Collection-Helpers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I'm trying to get some related data in angular-meteor with the help of these two packages:

Meteor-Collection-Helpers: https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers
Meteor-Publish-Composite: https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite

My setup looks like this:

model/groups.js

```
Groups = new Mongo.Collection("groups");
Groups.helpers({
    usersByScore: function () {
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: this.users}}, {sort: {score: -1}});
    }
});
Groups.allow({
    insert: function (userId, group) {
        return Roles.userIsInRole(userId, 'admin');
    },
    update: function (userId, group, fields, modifier) {
        return Roles.userIsInRole(userId, 'admin');
    },
    remove: function (userId, group) {
        return Roles.userIsInRole(userId, 'admin');
    }
});
```

server/groups.js

```
Meteor.publishComposite("groupsWithUsers", function () {
    return {
        find: function() {
            if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')) {
                return Groups.find({});
            } else {
                return Groups.find({users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: this.userId}}});
            }
        },
        children: [
            {
                find: function(group) {
                    return Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: (group.users) ? group.users : []}});
                }
            }
        ]
    };
});
```

client/matches/controller/scores.ng.js

```
angular.module('tippo').controller('ScoresController', ['$scope',
    function($scope){
        $scope.groups = Groups.find().fetch();
    }
]);
```

client/matches/views/scores.ng.html

```
<div ng-controller="ScoresController">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
            <md-tab label="{{ group.name }}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <md-list>
                        <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="user in group.usersByScore()">
                            <span>({{ user.score }})</span>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-divider></md-divider>
                    </md-list>
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

client/routes.js

```
angular.module('tippo').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider.state('scores', {
            url: '/scores',
            templateUrl: 'client/matches/views/scores.ng.html',
            controller: 'ScoresController',
            resolve: {
                'subscribe': ['$meteor', function($meteor) {
                    return $meteor.subscribe('groupsWithUsers');
                }],
                "currentUser": ["$meteor", function($meteor){
                    return $meteor.requireUser();
                }]
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Publish/Subscribe part is working fine, i can get all groups and related users via console, but as soon as i add the "user in group.usersByScore()", i get alot of these errors:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":29,"oldVal":26}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":32,"oldVal":29}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":35,"oldVal":32}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":38,"oldVal":35}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":41,"oldVal":38}]]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…rInterceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A41%2C%22oldVal%22%3A38%7D%5D%5D
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:68)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15723)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15953)
at safeApply (angular-meteor-meteorCollection.js:154)
at Object.angularMeteorCollections.factory.AngularMeteorCollection.updateCursor.self.observeHandle.cursor.observe.addedAt (angular-meteor-meteorCollection.js:174)
at LocalCollection._observeFromObserveChanges.observeChangesCallbacks.addedBefore (observe.js:96)
at Object.LocalCollection._CachingChangeObserver.self.applyChange.addedBefore (observe.js:33)
at minimongo.js:373
at _.extend.runTask (fiber_stubs_client.js:42)
at _.extend.flush (fiber_stubs_client.js:70)

Exception in queued task: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":29,"oldVal":26}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":32,"oldVal":29}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":35,"oldVal":32}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":38,"oldVal":35}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":41,"oldVal":38}]]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…rInterceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A41%2C%22oldVal%22%3A38%7D%5D%5D
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?c3a778493846e58a63e652cd68b47914889a794c:98:12)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?c3a778493846e58a63e652cd68b47914889a794c:15753:19)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?c3a778493846e58a63e652cd68b47914889a794c:15983:24)
at safeApply (http://localhost:3000/packages/urigo_angular.js?3cfbb5ec69330c7589d9a07bff661ca2dd28d04d:1173:47)
at Object.angularMeteorCollections.factory.AngularMeteorCollection.updateCursor.self.observeHandle.cursor.observe.addedAt (http://localhost:3000/packages/urigo_angular.js?3cfbb5ec69330c7589d9a07bff661ca2dd28d04d:1193:11)
at LocalCollection._observeFromObserveChanges.observeChangesCallbacks.addedBefore (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:3862:28)
at Object.LocalCollection._CachingChangeObserver.self.applyChange.addedBefore (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:3799:56)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:415:13
at _.extend.runTask (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:693:11)
at _.extend.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:721:10)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it happens is because `usersByScore()` returns a new object instance each time the function is called. So the digest cycle thinks the object is constantly being updated and gives up to avoid getting stuck.

Currently stuck on the same problem so I don't know how to fix it (yet).

edit: Having looked into this problem rather extensively, I'd have to conclude it just can't be done without major changes to angular-meteor.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The call of a collection helper of a document of a collection in a ng-repeat loop caused a digest loop.

In my situation I had collection of people with each person in a number of teams (array of team IDs on the person's document).

After investigation of the problem I came to a similar conclusion as @mpkorstanje. Finally I found myself implementing an angular-meteor helper in the client app and ditch the collection helper for this case.

My angular-meteor helper implementation looked like this:

```
// persistent instance cache
this.teamsMap = [];

this.helpers({
    teams() {
        const members = People.find({}).fetch();

        members.forEach(member => {
            this.teamsMap[member._id] = member.teams.map(team => Teams.findOne(team));
        });
    }
});
```

And a controller function to access the teams of the person in the view:

```
getTeams(member) {
    return this.teamsMap[member._id];
}
```

With this implementation the reactivity and view binding works as desired and I get no digest loop. Unfortunately it has a hacky taste. Hope it helps someone as a workaround.